# How to generate location information when using proxes to bypass CORS handling

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I've been searching topic like that here for two days and all I found was some proxies and sites like crossorigin.me.

The URL I want to access and parse is generating values with location, so when I get info via a proxy like `http://crossorigin.me` the value is not generated for me but instead for `crossorigin.me`'s server.
Is there any way to get this data with the originating location information?

Here is the document I want to parse.

```html
<VAST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vast.xsd" version="3.0">
  <Ad id="140128691667">
    <InLine>
      <AdSystem></AdSystem>
      <AdTitle>image</AdTitle>
      <Description>
        <![CDATA[ image ad ]]>
      </Description>
      <Error>
        <![CDATA[
    https://example.com[ERRORCODE]
    ]]>
      </Error>
      <Impression>
        <![CDATA[
    https://example.com
    ]]>
      </Impression>
```

Comment: Load it on the server and parse it. Even if you found a hack in clientscripting to do this right now, I would not build anything on shaky ground.

Comment: Can you please add what exactly you are trying to do? It is not clear at all

Comment: i have url(secured by cross domain),that url generates code i posted above,i want to parse for example <impression> tag.

Comment: @lain how can i do it? that url i want to parse isn't on my server.url secured by cross origin,i tried with file_Get_contents php,and getJson but it doesnt work

Comment: Perhaps the site you are accessing has an API you can use?

Comment: @mplungjan nope there is no API.